# Why a console.log in Node.js can interfere with a permutation of variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am really surprised of how `Node` (v8.5.0) interprets this code :

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

console.log('a = ' + a)
console.log('b = ' + b)

[a, b] = [b, a];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

The response is

```
[a, b] = [b, a];
   ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '10' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pom/lab/ES6-tests/destructuring.js:25:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:626:3
```

If I keep only the var in the console.log, the display is correct

```
console.log(a)
console.log(b)

[a, b] = [b, a];
```

What is doing this?

Comment: It says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '10' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:7:8` in google chrome for me.

Comment: I get the TypeError if i paste all the code into the console and execute it as a whole. But, if I run it in groups of two lines at a time, it compiles without error.

Comment: If you put all the semi-colons in it'll be fine. This is being treated as `console.log('b = ' + b)[a, b] = [b, a];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of an invalid left-hand side argument, probably due to a parsing issue.

The reason is that you are lacking a semi-colon after the console.log call, which confuses the interpreter and seemingly results in the concatenation of the two lines of code. You can see that with the semi-colon it works, and without, not.

```js
console.log("works");
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

console.log('a = ' + a);
console.log('b = ' + b);

[a, b] = [b, a];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```js
console.log("fails (with no semi-colon)");
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

console.log('a = ' + a)
console.log('b = ' + b)

[a, b] = [b, a];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```